# perl: reading from a file and/or stdin without using while(<>)

Tags: perl

For cases where one wishes to avoid the useful `while(<>)` syntax and manage file input manually, how does one handle the operation of reading from a list of files and/or `STDIN`? To read from files, one can simply iterate through `@ARGV`, opening each element in turn (e.g., `my $file=shift @ARGV; open(my $fh,'<',$file); while(<$fh>) {...}; close($fh);`. To read from standard input, one can simply use `while(<STDIN>) { ...}`. However, assuming the programmer expects similar types of data to be provided through STDIN and file arguments, the body of code within each `while` loop would have to be duplicated. I have tried unsuccessfully to assign STDIN to a filehandle (e.g., `my $fh = \*STDIN` or `my $fh = *STDIN{IO}`, each of which I have seen suggested elsewhere on this website). In essence, I would like to iterate through all files as well as `STDIN` and treat the input from each identically, but without using the handy `while(<>)` syntax. Could you please sketch a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With two-arg open (like `<>` uses), you could do

```
@ARGS = '-' if !@ARGV;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
    open($fh, $qfn);

    while (<$fh>) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Which three-arg `open`, I might do

```
@ARGV = \*STDIN if !@ARGV;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
    my $fh;
    if (ref($qfn)) {
       $fh = $qfn;
    } else {
       open($fh, '<', $qfn);
    }

    while (<$fh>) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is assigning a scalar, `-` to an array kosher?

Comment: @Mr. Llama, A list consisting of a single scalar is still a list, since a list simply means "zero or more scalars". As long as the RHS of the assignment evaluates to zero or more scalars (which all expressions do), you're ok.

Comment: Thank you — your answer is very helpful (I opted for the three-argument solution). Could you please also show how one would handle the (rare) case in which the user simultaneously pipes in data to the script and provides files as arguments? I believe the `while (<>)` syntax can handle such a situation. Can one simply `push(@ARGV,\*STDIN)` and detect later whether it is devoid of content (ignoring it, if so)? Finally, I am curious to know the significance of the abbreviation `qfn`.

Comment: `script file1 file2 - file4` will read stdin as the third file, without help fromthis solution. This is the only reasonable way to do it, since stdin is never "devoid of content": It is always open (unless you explicitly close it), and a program that tries to read from it will wait for terminal input.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (if you can use CPAN modules) is to use [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-All/lib/IO/All.pod).

Read a file into a scalar variable:

```
my $content1 < io('file1');
```

Another way to do it with IO::ALL:

```
my $content2 = io('file1')->slurp;
```

Or if you want it in an array, with each line as an element:

```
my @lines = io('file1')->slurp;
```