# How can I read from both STDIN and files passed as command line arguments without using `while(<>)`?

Tags: perl

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34127701/873757) demonstrates how one can read from `STDIN` *or* from a file, without using the null filehandle (i.e., `while(<>)`). However, I'd like to know how can one address situations where input may come from files, `STDIN`, or both simultaneously.

For instance, the `<>` syntax can handle such a situation, as demonstrated by the following minimal example:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc' | \
  while read x; do echo $x > ${x}".txt"; done; echo "d" | \
  perl -e "while(<>) {print;}" {a,b,c}.txt -
a
b
c
d
```

How can I do this without using `while(<>)`?

I want to avoid using `<>` because I want to handle each file independently, rather than aggregating all input as a single stream of text. Moreover, I want to do this without testing for `eof` on every line of input.

Comment: Your post answered its own question, in a way: the `<>` operator can be used to read from files named on the command line and then from standard input. What is an example of a situation that you want to handle that _isn't_ addressed by this operator?

Comment: @TimPierce: I want to avoid using the default syntax because I want to handle each file independently, rather than aggregating all input as a single stream of text. Therefore, I require a solution that does not rely on the `while(<>)` construct. Moreover, I want to do this without testing for `eof` on every line of input.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `eof`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I simply do not want to test for it on every line of input (e.g., `while(<>) {unless(eof) {...}}` or `while(<>){...} continue {if(eof) {...}}`. If there are thousands of files, that is a lot of conditionals, which can be avoided entirely by analyzing the input on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: @user001 Have you benchmarked and found a genuine performance bottleneck?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: No, I have not benchmarked yet, but I could make a comparison of the two alternative input handling formulations after I have finished.

Comment: I ran a very rough benchmark on ~500,000 files and found that the time added by calling `eof` was insignificant compared to the time required to open and read the files. I would recommend you do a similar benchmark for your application before going through contortions like this.

Comment: Also, note that common \*nix utilities like cat, sed, and awk by default handle either command line args *or* STDIN. Out of curiosity, why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thanks, that's good to know. I will perform a similar benchmark. Since this is a perl script, I wanted to replicate the behavior of the customary `while(<>)` operation as closely as possible. However, I agree that reading both `STDIN` and a file list is rather unusual.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the question whose answer this question links???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle each file independently of the others, you should loop over the arguments that have been given and open each file in turn:

```
for (@ARGV) {
    open(my $fh, '<', $_) || die "cannot open $_";
    while (<$fh>) {
        ... process the file here ...
    }
}
# handle standard input
while (<STDIN>) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @ Tim Actually you don't need the separate processing loop on most systems, since you can send in `/dev/stdin` as the file and the first loop will process it as the other files. @user001 You won't have to worry about checking for `EOF` as long as you send it in.

Comment: That's true, but if the tool is supposed to process standard input whether or not the user explicitly supplied `/dev/stdin` on the command line, it will need to do something explicit there. I suppose it could append `"/dev/stdin"` to the input argument list. At any rate, I think it's informative to call out that the `STDIN` filehandle is predefined and can be used directly without opening it as a file.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked post (http://stackoverflow.com/q/34127513/873757), I would like to avoid separate loops for `STDIN` and files, since this necessitates duplicating the code. The assumption is that the input from either source can be treated identically. I would like to be able to handle cases such as `<some-cmd> | perl script.pl` as well as `<some-cmd> | perl script.pl a b c -`. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Danischewski: How does one perform `eof`-dependent actions without checking for `eof` in a loop context (e.g., `while(<>)`) when there are multiple input files? Thanks.

Comment: You can certainly put the file processing code into a subroutine so that you don't have to duplicate large bodies of code. Also, as @A.Danischewski observed, you can append `"/dev/stdin"` to the argument list to handle standard input in the same loop as the other files. You should have more than enough to work with now to solve the rest of this problem.

Comment: @user001 When you supply `/dev/stdin` as one of the files the `while` loop reading the file is intrinsically checking for an `EOF` so you need not supply it. You can redirect a file to the script -or- pipe data from a file; otherwise, it will wait on input at that point you can simply type into the program and cease entering input with an `EOF` (usually `Ctrl-D`). So you can do: `echo "hello world" | handler.pl /dev/stdin`, `handler.pl /dev/stdin < file.txt`, `handler.pl /dev/stdin file.txt < anotherfile.txt`, `handler.pl /dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea based on Tim's that checks if STDIN has something to read (`NON BLOCKING STDIN`). This is useful if you don't really care about a user entering input manually from STDIN yet still want to be able to pipe and redirect data to the script.

`File: script.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use IO::Select;

$s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add(\*STDIN);
if ($s->can_read(0)) { push @ARGV, "/dev/stdin"; } 

for (@ARGV) {
    open(IN, "<$_") || die "** Error opening \"$_\": $!\n";
    while (<IN>) {
        print $_
    }
}
```

$> echo "hello world" | script.pl
 
hello world

$> script.pl < <(echo "hello world")
hello world

$> script.pl <(echo "hello world")
hello world

$> script.pl <<< "hello world"
hello world

$> script.pl
$>

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered by the Answer to which the question links.

```
@ARGS = '-' if !@ARGV;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
    open($fh, $qfn);

    while (<$fh>) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggested edit: change `@ARGS` to `@ARGV`